# Javascript API not working for Chrome or Safari on JW Player 5.9

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, safari, jwplayer

I am working on a custom interface for the JW Player which displays the current track title and has play/pause, next track, previous track and volume toggle buttons.

It works for IE8/9 and FF but fails for Chrome and Safari. Chrome's console gives the following error: *Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'addControllerListener'*

This is the code I am using for testing.

```
<div id="container">Loading the player ...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
        image: "preview.jpg",
        height: 320,
        width: 480,
        modes: [
            { type: "html5" },
            { type: "flash", src: "player.swf" }
        ],
        'playlist': [
            { 'file': "audio/01.mp3", 'title': "Track 1" },
            { 'file': "audio/02.mp3", 'title': "Track 2" },
            { 'file': "audio/03.mp3", 'title': "Track 3" }
        ],
    });

    function playerReady(obj)
    {
        player = document.getElementById(obj.id);
        displayFirstItem();
    };

    function displayFirstItem()
    {
        try
        {
            playlist = player.getPlaylist();
        }
        catch(e)
        { 
            setTimeout("displayFirstItem()", 100);
        }

        player.addControllerListener('ITEM', 'itemMonitor');
        itemMonitor({index:0});
    };

    function itemMonitor(obj)
    {
        $('#nowplaying').html('<span><strong>Now Playing:</strong> ' + playlist[obj.index]['title'] + '</span>');
    };
</script>
<div id="nowplaying"></div>
<div class="control_bar">
    <ul>
         <li onclick='player.sendEvent("play");'>[ &#8250; ] Play / Pause</li>
         <li onclick='player.sendEvent("prev");'>[ &laquo; ] Previous item</li>
         <li onclick='player.sendEvent("next");'>[ &raquo; ] Next item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have searched and tried several modifications, like adding the javascriptid parameter, nothing seems to work for Chrome or Safari.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short**

Remove `{ type: "html5" },`.

**Long**

HTML5 renders the player with divs and img tags and plays your videos and it doesn't support everything the flash version supports, including parts of the JS API.

Comment: That was it, thank you very much! 

Now flash is the default mode and html5 works as a reduced functionality fallback.

Comment: @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL, i have seme problem. But in few seconds after video start to play JS API of jwplayer is available, after that js api not working. Very strange. What it may be?

Comment: @Kalinin doesn't sound like anything to me. Open another question with code.

Comment: @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL, already opened: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800386/jw-player-javascript-api-not-working