# JW Player Movie Database service does not work for safari (all other browsers work)

Tags: javascript, vb.net, web-services, safari, jwplayer

I have a script that plays a movie given to it by a service.

```css
<div id="player1">Loading the player ...</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer('player1').setup({
        file: "downloadvideo.aspx",
        width: "296",
        height: "240",
        type: "mp4",
    });
</script>
```

Here is the form load event that gives the movie file:

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles     Me.Load

    Dim filePath As String = "C:\websites\Website2\wdo.mp4"
    Dim Buffer As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)

    Context.Response.Clear()
    Context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public)
    Context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now)
    Context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4")
    Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=wdo.mp4")
    Context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", Buffer.Length.ToString())

    Context.Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer)

End Sub
```

This works for Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Firefox. But not Safari.

In Safari it just has a progress circle that rotates forever.

If you directly give the script a movie file it plays it fine in safari, but i need to give the script the movie with this method because my movie's will be stored in a database.

Answer (score 0):

try this its working

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles     Me.Load

```
Dim filePath As String = "C:\websites\Website2\wdo.mp4"
Dim Buffer As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)

Context.Response.Clear()
Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=wdo.mp4")
Response.ContentType = "video/mp4"
Context.Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer)
```

End Sub

Comment: This just makes a rotating progress symbol and nothing happens.

Comment: I think there is add-on on the safari you have to configure

Comment: Can you please tell me the add-on settings you are talking about?

Comment: could you check the below may it help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809438/javascript-api-not-working-for-chrome-or-safari-on-jw-player-5-9